# How to multiselect in liferea?

Tags: liferea

The only reason why I didn't use liferea instead of rssowl is that I don't know how to select several newsitems for deleting. Because there isn't a "delete all"-functionality I have to select each headline, which loads the content, which is wasted; and by navigating through the list via keyboard I automatically mark other items as read, which is unintended.

Is multiselection possible in liferea, and if yes, how? (and if no, why the...not?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in Liferea for simplicity. Multi-selection causes complex scenarios for all possible headline related menu options.